# How is $\sum\limits_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{k^e}{k^\pi}$ divergent?

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

Can somebody explain to me how this series diverges by using the P-Series test?

$$\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{k^e}{k^\pi}$$

My guess was convergence, due to $p > 1$, because $p = \pi$. However, according to Wolframalpha it diverges.

Comment: You should recall that the P-Series test requires for the summand to be of the form $\frac{1}{k^{p}}$. Compare this to the current for that you have yours in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: rewrite it as

$$\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{k^e}{k^{\pi}} = \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^{\pi-e}}.$$

What is your $p$ here?

Comment: Ohhh, nice. About .40. Thanks man!

Comment: You got it! $\,\,$